# /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 15: [-d: command not found

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am using vagrant on a rails project. I' am checking to make sure that RVM is not globally installed and uninstalling RVM if it is with this script:

```
if [-d "/usr/local/rvm"]; then
    yes yes | sudo rvm implode
fi
```

I'm getting this error in output `/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 15: [-d: command not found`

Why isn't -d working?

Comment: Either you posted the wrong line, or you added the space between `[` and `-d` in the question. The error indicates the code being executed lacks that space.

Comment: Hah! I did add the space before I posted. I didn't think it would matter! Let me edit the question. Go ahead and add your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space between `[` and `-d` is required, as `[` is not special syntax, but a simple command name. As such, `[-d` is also a valid command name, but one that is unlikely to be found.